# Kubernetes: failed to mount unformatted volume as read only

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to use gcePersistentDisk as ReadOnlyMany so that my pods on multiple nodes can read the data on this disk. Following the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks) for the same.

To create and later format the gce Persistent Disk, I have followed the instructions in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk). Following this doc, I have sshed into one of the nodes and have formatted the disk. See below the complete error and also the other yaml files.

**kubectl describe pods -l podName**

```
Name:               punk-fly-nodejs-deployment-5dbbd7b8b5-5cbfs
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               gke-mycluster-default-pool-b1c1d316-d016/10.160.0.12
Start Time:         Thu, 25 Apr 2019 23:55:38 +0530
Labels:             app.kubernetes.io/instance=punk-fly
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=nodejs
                    pod-template-hash=1866836461
Annotations:        kubernetes.io/limit-ranger=LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container nodejs
Status:             Pending
IP:
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/punk-fly-nodejs-deployment-5dbbd7b8b5
Containers:
  nodejs:
    Container ID:
    Image:          rajesh12/smartserver:server
    Image ID:
    Port:           3002/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False

    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment:
      MYSQL_HOST:           mysqlservice
      MYSQL_DATABASE:       app
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  password
    Mounts:
      /usr/src/ from helm-vol (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-jpkzg (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  helm-vol:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  my-readonly-pvc
    ReadOnly:   true
  default-token-jpkzg:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-jpkzg
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age               From                                               Message
  ----     ------                  ----              ----                                               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               2m                default-scheduler                                  Successfully assigned default/punk-fly-nodejs-deployment-5dbbd7b8b5-5cbfs to gke-mycluster-default-pool-b1c1d316-d016
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  1m                attachdetach-controller                            AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-9c796180-677e-11e9-ad35-42010aa0000f"
  Warning  FailedMount             10s (x8 over 1m)  kubelet, gke-mycluster-default-pool-b1c1d316-d016  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "pvc-9c796180-677e-11e9-ad35-42010aa0000f" : failed to mount unformatted volume as read only
  Warning  FailedMount             0s                kubelet, gke-mycluster-default-pool-b1c1d316-d016  Unable to mount volumes for pod "punk-fly-nodejs-deployment-5dbbd7b8b5-5cbfs_default(86293044-6787-11e9-ad35-42010aa0000f)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"punk-fly-nodejs-deployment-5dbbd7b8b5-5cbfs". list of unmounted volumes=[helm-vol]. list of unattached volumes=[helm-vol default-token-jpkzg]
```

**readonly_pv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-readonly-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 1G
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: mydisk0
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-readonly-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1G
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
  volumes:
    - name: helm-vol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-readonly-pvc
        readOnly: true
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Values.app.backendName }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tagServer }}"
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
      env:
      - name: MYSQL_HOST
        value: mysqlservice
      - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
        value: app
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: password
      ports:
        - name: http-backend
          containerPort: 3002
      volumeMounts:
        - name: helm-vol
          mountPath: /usr/src/
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your [PVC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) is dynamically provisioning a new volume that is not formatted with the [default StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/)

It could be that your Pod is being created in a different availability from where you have the [PV](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) provisioned. The gotcha with having multiple Pod readers for the gce volume is that the Pods always have to be in the same availability zone.

Some options:

- Simply create and format the [PV](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) on the same availability zone where your node is.
- When you define your PV you could specify [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#node-affinity) to make sure it always gets assigned to a specific node.
- Define a [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) that specifies the filesystem

  ```
  kind: StorageClass
  apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: mysc
  provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
  parameters:
    type: gp2
    fsType: ext4
  ```

  And then use it in your PVC:

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: my-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadOnlyMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 1G
    storageClassName: mysc
  ```

  The volume will be automatically provisioned and formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message when trying to provision a persistent disk with an access mode of `ReadWriteOnce`. What fixed the issue for me was removing the property `readOnly: true` from the `volumes` declaration of the Deployment spec. In the case of your `deployment.yaml` file, that would be this block:

```
volumes:
- name: helm-vol
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: my-readonly-pvc
    readOnly: true
```

Try removing that line and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and managed to fix it using a few lines from a related article about using preexisting disks
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd

You need to add `storageClassName` and `volumeName` to your persistent volume claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-demo
spec:
  # It's necessary to specify "" as the storageClassName
  # so that the default storage class won't be used, see
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1
  storageClassName: ""
  volumeName: pv-demo
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500G
```